# Edit product hook WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

On my product template, I execute this action :

```
<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_single_product_summary hook.
    *
    * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
    * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
    * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
    * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
    * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
    * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
    * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
    */
   do_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary');
?>
```

What I want is to edit `woocommerce_template_single_excerpt` so I wrote this code in **functions.php** :

```
add_action('woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 'woocommerce_custom_single_excerpt', 20);

function woocommerce_custom_single_excerpt() {
    global $post;
    echo '<p class="product-description">';
    echo $post->post_excerpt;
    echo '</p>';
}
```

But it does not override at all.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this code snippet.

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_custom_single_excerpt', 15);

function woocommerce_custom_single_excerpt() {
    global $post;
    echo '<p class="product-description">';
    echo "hello";
    echo '</p>';
}
```